# Multiple structs containing an instance of eachother

Tags: c, struct

For an assignment I need to declare multiple structs, no problem there. These are declared like:

```
typedef struct struct1{
  struct2* object;
}

typedef struct struct2{
  struct1* object;
}

// functions using both struct1 and struct2 parameters
```

Ofcourse, this will give me an error, as struct2 isn't declared previous to struct1. Therefore, I tried declaring it beforehand, by putting

```
struct struct2;
```

at the top. This however requires me to call the object within the struct1 block as

```
typedef struct struct1{
  struct struct2* obj;
}
```

The functions this structure will be used in use      struct1* and     struct2*    parameters, and get tested as such (including the constructor). Using a struct tag as in the above example will give me countless errors. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef struct s2 struct2;

typedef struct s1 {
  struct2* object;
} struct1;

struct s2 {
  struct1* object;
};
```

Comment: I tried it with gcc `gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)` and I get the following error `main.c:12:3: error: redefinition of typedef ‘struct2’
main.c:4:19: note: previous declaration of ‘struct2’ was here
`

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: `gcc 4.7.2` didn't by default warn about this, but you are quite right. I've corrected the answer.